# Adobe Premiere Pro to fast forward faster

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere

I am using Adobe Premiere Pro for the best part of 5 years and one thing that has always stumped me is the ability to fast forward through a video.

When previewing files i need to move through them quickly and take out the important parts by setting mark-in and mark-outs and then just inserting them into my timeline.

Its just not fast enough. I believe at full speed its around x6 fast forward.

Is there a way to increase this speed?

I am using CS6.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complex question well beyond a simple answer without knowing your PC's specs and CS6 setting. You might want to investigate CUDA acceleration in CS6 on Google or the Adobe help pages. Basically, if you have an nVidia CUDA supported/accelerated card in your pc, all video scrubbing, editing will be in real time, like you want it to be.

You might also google 'Generic Disk Setup' to get an understanding of how to setup harddisks for video editing.

If you are editing simple video, use premiere elements rather than cs6.

You can also drastically increase scrubbing speed by using the K and L keys, as they are used for scrubbing through footage at different speeds.

Comment: cheers for the answer fella. I've no problems with speed of the video, the issue is i want the video to physically increase in speed. So at the moment it fast forwards at 6x i want it to go at 32x for example. My machine is purpose built for HD video editing. 16gb DDR3 Ram 8-core 590 nVidia etc